# How Can I get muitiple files selected to the same application launch from a "right click" context menu (windows explorer)

Tags: contextmenu, registry

I am able to get a shell registry type context menu function to work , see below . But is there a way to tell windows to send multiple files selected to the same application , perhaps instead of %1 or %L some other parameter . What happens now is that it launches the associated application for each file in the list .

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\sendtomyapp]
@="&Upload to (File*Pics)Mojo"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\sendtomyapp\command]
@="c:\Program Files\app_directory\App.exe -n \"%1\""

Is there a way to send an array of names like sys.args in python ?

Comment: I think this question should be asked at superuser.com

Comment: This is a developer question, so no.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is to look into DDEExec instead of shell\open\command.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165967(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a superuser.com question, but I think these kind of operations require a bit of code. e.g. you write a proxy program that accepts the files, and adds them to an execution queue or batch of another program (like adding several files to a media player) I don't know if what you are looking for is supported inherently in Windows

Answer (score 0):

You will need a full shell extension DLL to do what you want to do here. So the answer is programming even if the question was not.